# Object tag is not working when i use it inside HTML5 video tag?

Tags: cross-browser, html5-video, object-tag

I have webpage that needs to display video but i will have two files

1) .ogg file with Theora Codec

2) .mp4 file with MPEG4 Codec

I have written below HTML but it did not worked as i expected in IE and Microsoft Edge.

Guys please figure out where i went wrong ?

```
<video id="my-video">
    <source src="video/Videoogg.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <object type="video/mpeg" data="video/video.mp4"  width="320" height="240"> 
</video>
```

Comment: Please state 1) what you expected to happen, 2) what actually happened

Comment: what i am expecting is it should fallback to the object tag whenever browser does not support Theora codec